# Compare a string whose content comes from a table with the sheet name and delete if it is the same name

Tags: excel, vba

I try to compare a string with the worksheet Name. The only difference between the string and the sheet name is that the sheet name has a number. For example: `string = test` and `sheet.name = 1` test. The string gets the value from a table in Excel and after the string is like the sheet name the sheet should get deleted. I tried it with like but it didn't work.

```
If lsoData.DataBodyRange.Cells(lngCount, 2) = "yes" Then
     strSheet = lsoData.DataBodyRange.Cells(lngCount, 1)
     'Loop through the sheets
     For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          If strSheet Like xWs.Name Then
              xWs.Delete
              lsoData.DataBodyRange.Cells(lngCount, 1).Delete
          End If
     Next
```

I expected that the sheet gets deleted cause the string is the same. I know that I normally Need "* *" when I am searching for something with like but my string is different with every loop. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You need wildcard(s). `strSheet Like "*" & xWs.Name & "*"`.

Comment: thank you, i got the answer before seeing your comment, but it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I just needed to add `"*"` before and after my string:

```
strSheet = "*" + lsoData.DataBodyRange.Cells(lngCount, 1) + "*"
```

Comment: Note that for string concatentation you should use `&` and not `+`. If you use `+` Excel tries to calculate. For example `1 & "1"` results in "1 1" but `1 + "1"` results in `2`. So make sure you use `&` if your plan is to concatenate strings and `+` if your plan is to calculate.